# How does libgdx draw text in a 3D perspective?

Tags: java, libgdx

I would like to render fixed text for debugging in my guiCam (second camera that is not affected by any rotations or transformations).

I think the text that is being rendered is either to big or to small to be seen in my perspective here, but I can't seem to find in the official libgdx documentation how the text is being draw and how I can manipulate the size.

create:

```
guiCam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        guiCam.position.set(1f, 1f, 20f);
        guiCam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        guiCam.near = 1f;
        guiCam.far = 300f;
        guiCam.update();

batch = new SpriteBatch();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(guiCam.combined);

        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
```

render:

```
font.draw(batch, "debug line here", 200, 200);
```

Could someone perhaps explain to me how the libgdx default font is drawn, or if there might be a better solition to use here for displaying fixed text?

I allready tried to use OrthoGraphic camera instead of a prespective one, but since my main application is in 3D, the OrthoGraphic camera is does not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Found this for you on stackexchange.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31379/how-do-i-make-an-on-screen-hud-in-libgdx)

Answer given by lookx2:

You can just use another SpriteBatch without setting projection matrix to draw the HUD,

```
camera.update();
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
spriteBatch.begin();
aButton.draw(spriteBatch, 1F);
playerShip.draw(spriteBatch, 1F);
spriteBatch.end();

hudBatch.begin();
//Draw using hudBatch
hudBatch.end();
```

If you want to render text on the screen then you'd want to do that by drawing to the HUD

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I use two camera's the problem being that I am using a 3D camera and not the 2D OrthoGraphic camera. I'm using a seperate batch for the font and I have set that batch' projection matrix to be the guiCam.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it even works by mixing 2d and 3d batches. You should use `Stage` and StringBuilder with a single perspective camera.

For example, in `create()` function initialise the following

```
...
font = new BitmapFont();
//design the font
label = new Label("<text>", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.BLACK)); 
// set position
label.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
stage = new Stage();
stage.addActor(label);
...
```

then in `render()` function use `StringBuilder`

```
...
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//Change text at runtime    
builder.append("<text>");
label.setText(builder);
stage.draw();
...
```

The example that helped me use it is from https://sudonull.com/post/91327-The-simplest-3D-game-on-libGDX-for-Android-in-200-lines-of-code